# drupal validate before resetting password in one time login

Tags: drupal

I want to set a password length(min 6 characters) to my reset password after a one time login link is clicked,it contains password and confirm password only.

I know there are specific module available,but i do not want to use it

because my drupal is heavily moded.

I have written a custom module  ,im not sure whether the function im using are

correct..

Also it has to accept Alphanumeric and special characters  :

```
function userfieldslength_validate_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

   if ( $form_id =='user_pass_reset') {
   echo "===>>>>>>>>";
      $form['#validate'][] = 'userfieldslength_validate_form_alter_user_profile_validate';
   }


    return $form;
 }

 function userfieldslength_validate_form_alter_user_profile_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  echo "===>>>>>>>>";
  if(!empty($form_state['values']['pass']) && strlen($form_state['values']['pass'])>30){
    form_set_error('pass', 'Password must be less than 30 characters. Please correct password');
  }
  if(!empty($form_state['values']['pass']) && strlen($form_state['values']['pass'])<6){
    form_set_error('pass', 'Password must be at least 6 characters long. Please correct password');
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? I would personally use the [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) function so your alter would not run on every form and you would not need the if statement to check you have the correct form.

Comment: The problem is the above functionis not working.Its not validating..Hav eit written the correct function?